# I'm using a kuberctl(on my computer) to use the minikuber(on the other server), but how to start it?

Tags: config, kubectl

The OS: Ubuntu 16.04;

On my computer: need a kuberctl to use the minikube,

On the server: a minikube on it and running already,

The net: both my computer and server are in one net, route is OK,

---

Question: I have downloaded a kuberctl binary tag.gz already, how to start and config my kuberctl?

I've unzipped the kuberctl binary tag.gz, but I don't know what to do next...

In fact, no code by now.

I hope to config the kuberctl and start it; the documentation seems help nothing.

Comment: Did you follow https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow instructions described [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/). You need to specify connection properties for your `kubectl` binary using a configuration file. To do that you'll need to know the Minikube configuration on your server.

Make sure that the minikube cluster is accepting connections from external addresses and there are no firewall rules blocking the connection.

After that, you should be able to use kubectl on your local computer to control that minikube cluster.

Also, it's `kubectl` and not `kuberctl`.